# A multiplication problem: $OUI \times OUI = OOUUI + OOUUI$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, puzzle

Here's a $6$th-grade exam problem:

$$OUI \times OUI = OOUUI + OOUUI$$

$O, U$ and $I$ are digits.
e.g $365 \times 365 =  33665 + 33665$ (not the case)

Thus, because the digits are into account I believe there's no algebraic equation. Also, $6$th graders don't even know algebra anyway.

With some extremely clever insight, someone could end up with the conclusion that $I=2$, pretty fast, and that it has to be $212 > OUI > 102$, giving only $10$ possibilities to test out.

There's a catch though; They don't have calculators. Can you tell me what kind of thinking or if there's an analytical solution?

Comment: I changed the tag from [tag:abstract-algebra] to [tag:puzzle]

Comment: The product of two numbers ending in 5 will end in a 5.  The sum of two numbers ending in 5 will end in 0.  I dont know where you get 365*365.... I know you said it wasnt right but Im wondering why it was even a consideration.

Comment: I just quickly used 3 different digit sorted randomly from the mind hat. No thinking was involved. The answer is 152.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone who has done puzzles like this will get $I=2$ quickly.  We need $I^2$ to end with the same digit as $2I$.  Next would be to see $O=1$.  If $O=2$ it conflicts with $I$ and if $O$ is greater $O^2 \gt 2\cdot O$.  We are now down to eight possibilities for $U$.  Multiplying by hand to check if the tens digit of $UI^2$ is the same as the tens digit of $2\cdot UI$ is not too much work.  It is only a two digit multiply and you don't have to do the hundreds column.

Comment: SO you don't think it was meant for them to find an analytic solution?

Comment: Those were the exact thought I had, but I couldn't verify them.

Comment: I think this is the intended approach.  I would call the first two, $I,O$ analytic.  A small number of checks are in range of the effort expected.  To me, that includes eight two digit multiplies.  It depends on the time per question.  I would say this is a five minute answer if they are practiced in these questions.